# Getting start location of Flick gesture in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, monogame

I'm using MonoGame implementation of XNA to create a Windows Phone game. The player should be able to move objects across the level using flick gestures. I'm using the `TouchPanel` class to read gestures.

Here's how I initialize the TouchPanel:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Flick;
```

Here is how I read the gestures in `Update` method:

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    var g = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
    ...
}
```

However, the only field that is filled is the `Delta` vector. But how do I find out the point from where the user has started the gesture?

Since I want my game to be cross-platform, I cannot rely on non-XNA code such as Silverlight gesture handlers.

Comment: The XNA documentation says Flicks are positionless so it's behaving as designed. Have you checked to see if Tap occurs before Flick? Alternately, you might be able to use FreeDrag or use TouchPanel.GetState and do your own custom logic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using `Flick` gesture to move objects is not a good idea, as Flicks are positionless.
You should use `Hold` or `FreeDrag` gesture instead, detecting the object and then moving it across the screen.
The purpose of Flick is just zooming, I suggest you to choose another gesture.